# How to avoid the opening of jasper viewer when there is no document found?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am creating java desktop application. I am using jasper report to create report.  **Is there some method to call saying to JasperViewer doesn't appear if 
the ResultSet doesn't contain any data? I only want the message dialog 
''The document has no pages.".**

Comment: As alternative variant you can use ***No Data*** band

Answer (score 1):

You can show report generation button if data available. Some way you have to check data available for given condition

Answer (score 0):

You could do the query and process the results into a list and send that list to Jasper. That way, you could check the query results for data before passing things on to Jasper. If there's nothing, you show your dialog, if there's data, have Jasper show it.

If you don't think that having a report created that informs the user that there's no data is a problem for the user, Alex K's suggestion of utilizing the ***No Data*** band would be quicker and easier to implement.

Answer (score 0):

The following approach works for JasperReports-3.5.2:

```
JasperPrint jPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(...);
JasperViewer jViewer = new JasperViewer(jPrint, false);
if (jPrint.getPages().isEmpty()) {
    // JasperViewer constructor displayed "the document has no pages" dialog
    // so rather than displaying the empty JasperViewer simply return.
    return;
}
jViewer.setVisible(true);
```